# Informative texts on psychoanalysis?

Tags: psychoanalysis

I'm not looking for anything all-inclusive, as I am aware that such a list would be impossible. Perhaps some introductory books on psychoanalysis (such as works by Freud) would be good, as well as any compilation of case studies, etc.

Comment: Also see: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/18092/7001

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for this:

https://www.valas.fr/IMG/pdf/Freud_Complete_Works.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Psychoanalysis, you cannot go far wrong with starting by having a look at the [4-part YouTube Video Series put together by the Freud Museum of London](https://www.freud.org.uk/education/topic/76249/what-is-psychoanalysis-is-it-weird/) along with their article which gives an outline on Freud's Theories [(Are Freud's Theories All About Sex?)](https://www.freud.org.uk/education/topic/10567/subtopic/10571/)

Reading Freud's Complete Works as suggested by @GogaVachnadze could be heavy going if you are just starting off but will give a complete understanding.

There is also the excellent book of articles edited by Dr. Joseph Reppen, PhD. called Beyond Freud: A Study of Modern Psychoanalytic Theorists.  It was published by the [IPI (International Psychotherapy Institute)](https://theipi.org/) and is available free from their website at https://freepsychotherapybooks.org/psychoanalysis/product/40-beyond-freud-a-study-of-modern-psychoanalytic-theorists/category_pathway-17